# theming username field in user-register form

Tags: theming, forms

i'm trying to theming my user register form. i would like to have a custom function for the username part. So, i'm doing

```
$form['account']['name']['#theme'] = 'my_custom';
```

i define my hook_theme and just for testing purpouses, this is my custom function

```
function theme_my_custom( $variables ){
  return 'testing code...'
}
```

My problem is when i go to user/register, i still can see the label for my username. Only the input is replaced by the code of my function. I would expect replace the element entirely, but this is not happening.

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [Form API reference page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7), '#theme' Only affects the input box itself. To remove other things generated by the form API, you'll have to clear the array -

```
$form['account']['name']['#title'] => '';
$form['account']['name']['#description'] => '';
```

or just

```
$form['account']['name'] = array(...);
```

To reset existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

or you may use [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) property for your form elements.